# How can I prove that Cx will intersect x^2

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics

I want to disprove $ cx \geq x^2 \ \forall \ x $ where c is a real number. (i.e. show that x^2 is not O(x) )

So it seems that I can show that the two must intersect at some point ... if I divide both sides of the inequality by x (assuming a nonzero x, since I just need to disprove it *somewhere*)

$c \geq x \ \forall \ x $ but if x is a real number and c is a real number then there must be some value x that is less than c.

Is this logic sound?

Comment: I'm also not sure what tags are appropriate for this ...

Comment: Also you could disprove it by setting x=2c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $p(x)=x^2-cx$. Then $p(x)=0$ has two roots $0$ and $c$. For all $x\in (0,c)$ we have $p(x)<0$ that is  $x^2<cx$. But out of this interval $P(x)>0$ or $x^2>cx$. Therefore for an arbitrary $c$, both inequalities may occur.

Answer (score 1):

For any $c > 0$,
you can show two things:

(1) for small enough $x$,
$x^2 < cx$;

(2) for all large enough $x$,
$x^2 > cx$.

To make your proof rigorous,
you have to make the
"small enough"
and
"large enough"
explicit.

This implies that
$cx$ intersects $x^2$
at least once.